# Using NSDateFormatter..iPhone..webview

Tags: nsdateformatter

im trying to use the NSDateFormatter to turn the day into an integer and then to have a selection of IF statements which will show a different web page depending on what day it is in my web view, ive been banging my head against the wall for 2 days now and i can't figure out how to do it :(

Can anyone give me some advice? :)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

for converting the day into an integer you can try the following code

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];

[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd"];

int day = [[dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]] intValue];